# Controlling State Variable from Class

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a class designed to take care of complex operations called `UtilityClass` and is set up as:

```
export default class UtilityClass {
  constructor(name, setName) {
    this.name = name
    this.setName = setName
  }

  changeName(newName) {
    this.setName(newName)
  }

  printName() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

I want to initialise this class from my functional component and call its functions on button clicks:

```
import UtilityClass from './UtilityClass'

export function App(props) {
  const utilityClass = useRef()
  const [name, setName] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    utilityClass.current = new UtilityClass(name, setName)
  }, [])

  function setViaClass(newName) {
    utilityClass.current.changeName(newName)
  }

  function printViaClass() {
    utilityClass.current.printName()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setViaClass('Class')}>Set via class</button>
      <button onClick={printViaClass}>Print via class</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I call `UtilityClass.setName()`, the value of the state variable will change, but printing `this.name` from within `UtilityClass` will display `undefined`.

Why is `this.name` not synced with what the state value really is?

The reason I have `UtilityClass` instead of having the logic directly in my functional component is that the logic should be called across multiple functional components, and I want to split my code into smaller readable bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UtilityClass` has exactly one line where you assign to `this.name` - in the constructor. As a result

```
printName() {
  console.log(this.name)
}
```

will always print the initial name - the one passed when the class was constructed. Calling a state setter doesn't change the `UtilityClass` because you only create it once, in the effect hook here.

```
useEffect(() => {
  utilityClass.current = new UtilityClass(name, setName)
}, [])
```

You only create the class once, and you only pass in the name once, and you only set the property in the class once - so it never changes.

While it would be possible to refactor your class to account for this, to a limited extent - the whole concept doesn't really work well with React's functional paradigm. A much better approach that allows for the modularization of logic would be a custom hook that you call in each component that needs it. Here's an example of a hook that holds 2 state variables.

```js
const usePersonInfo = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('defaultname');
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
  return {
    name,
    setName,
    age,
    setAge,
    // Example method implementing special logic
    setAgeTo10: () => setAge(10)
  };
};

function App(props) {
  const { name, setName, age, setAge, setAgeTo10 } = usePersonInfo();
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input value={age} onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.valueAsNumber)} type="number" />
      <button onClick={setAgeTo10}>set age to 10</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

The above is the approach I like to use to separate out rendering logic from state manipulation logic, when a component starts to feel too large to fit both.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default `useState()` hook to manage your state, create a custom hook called `useStateWithCallback()` like this

```js
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export const useStateWithCallback = (initState) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
  const callbackRef = useRef(null);

  const setStateCallback = useCallback((state, callback) => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
    setState(state);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current(state);
      callbackRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setStateCallback];
}
```

In the `App` component, use this new hook to create the state that has to be managed by that utility class

```js
const [name, setName] = useStateWithCallback();
```

Now in the UtilityClass whenever you try to update the state using `this.setName` provide a callback function as the second argument

```js
export default class UtilityClass {
  constructor(name, setName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.setName = setName;
  }

  changeName(newName) {
    this.setName(newName, (newState) => {
        this.name = newState;
    });
  }

  printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```